# Sharepoint controls and webparts C# descriptions

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I am learning SharePoint with web parts and I am trying to figure out this sample code and what I does.
Here is the sample

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;

namespace SampleWebpart1

  {
    [Guid("cf5f3fd5-1776-4c47-9587-4f6fe4f3d645")]

    public class SampleWebpart1 : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart            
      {

          public SampleWebpart1() { }

          protected override void CreateChildControls()
            {
              base.CreateChildControls();
              SharePointCalendar calendar = new SharePointCalendar();
              Controls.Add(calendar);
            }
       }

    public class SharePointCalendar : Control

     {
       private SPCalendarView _view;
       /// Create the SharePoint calendar. Uses the SharePoint SPCalendarView object.
       protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
          base.CreateChildControls();
          _view = new SPCalendarView();
          _view.EnableViewState = true;
          _view.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
          _view.DataSource = GetCalendarItems();
          DataBind();
          Controls.Add(_view);
        }

      private SPCalendarItemCollection GetCalendarItems()
         {

           // Create a new collection for the calendar items
          // This is an item with a start and end date.
           SPCalendarItemCollection items = new SPCalendarItemCollection();
         // Add the first dummy item
           SPCalendarItem item = new SPCalendarItem();
           item.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
           item.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
           item.hasEndDate = true;
           item.Title = "First calendar item";
           item.DisplayFormUrl = "/News";
           item.Location = "USA";
           item.Description = "This is the first test item in the calendar rollup";
           item.IsAllDayEvent = false;
           item.IsRecurrence = false;
           item.CalendarType = Convert.ToInt32(SPCalendarType.Gregorian);
           items.Add(item);
         // Add the second item. This is an all day event.
        SPCalendarItem item2 = new SPCalendarItem();
        item2.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        item.hasEndDate = true;
        item2.Title = "Second calendar item";
        item2.DisplayFormUrl = "/News";
        item2.Location = "India";
        item2.Description = "This is the second test item in the calendar rollup";
        item2.IsAllDayEvent = true;
        item2.IsRecurrence = false;
        item2.CalendarType = Convert.ToInt32(SPCalendarType.Gregorian);
        items.Add(item2);
       // return the collection
        return items;
       }

      }

     }
```

So this is what I am working at My first question is what is this
[Guid("cf5f3fd5-1776-4c47-9587-4f6fe4f3d645")] mean or do. I have seen something like it in XNA but that was for content processing.

What does the : mean in this line public class SharePointCalendar : Control
Is that saying that the class sharpointcalendar extends controls?

What does all this do? and why is there a _ before view?

```
      _view = new SPCalendarView();
      _view.EnableViewState = true;
      _view.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
      _view.DataSource = GetCalendarItems();
```

Thanks for any help with this:)

Comment: These are pretty basic questions. Maybe you should learn C# first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _ dash is to state that the variable is private, this is optional and you can name them as you like. But most programming languages follows this pattern called naming conventions which I think you should know about before you start to develop in SharePoint! :)

- Public - first letter is upper case
- protected - first letter is lower case
- _private - first letter is the dash followed by a lower case letter

The GUID is the COM identifier that represents the class in question, it is used to identify your component by the outside world.

I see little or no reason having the guid there in this example unless you plan to run the webpart in a remote system or accessing it by an external assembly or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Before jumping into SharePoint development, you should learn C# and ASP.NET -both "C# Step-By-Step" and "ASP.NET Step-By-Step" (Microsoft Press) are great primers though there are any number of books you can start with.  Learn C# first, then move up to ASP.NET.  After that, you are ready to jump into SharePoint development.  A good starting point would be a book like "Beginning SharePoint 2010 Development" (WROX) Press.

GUID stands for "Globally Unique IDentifier" - it is a unique ID that can be assigned to *any* resource in Windows.  GUIDs might as well be called "Galactically Unique Identfiers" as it highly improbable that any two GUIDs will ever repeat.

The colon in the class declaration means that that the class inherits from control.